# PHP Delete File if other file exists

Tags: php, html

*Note: The file number is just so I can refer to each file easier*

I am testing some code in which I have a file called `first.txt` (file 1) and and file called `tom-first.php` (file 2), file 2 file checks for the file 1's existence and sets a variable, then in my `index.php`(file 3), I require file 2 and if the variable is 1, I redirect to `startup.php`(file 4). File 4 deletes a text file called `text.txt`

My error is when I run the code, no matter what happens, test.txt is always deleted

**tom-first.php**

```
<?php

if (file_exists('first.txt')) {
    $first = '1';
} else {
    $first = '0';
}

echo $first;
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'tom-first.php';
if($first = '1')
{
    header("Location: startup.php");
}
else
{
    echo 'HI';
}


?>
```

**Startup.php**

```
<?php
unlink('text.txt') 
?>
```

**First.txt is Empty**

I feel like the error is to do with setting variables on file 2 although echoing out $first shows the right number.

Any help is appreciated, even a completely different method of this would be useful, I am basically trying to make a system where it has a setup that runs on first time use.

Comment: Your code is ok. If `test.txt` exists, it is (always) deleted. If it don't exists, it is not (obviously) deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in **index.php** file.

Equality comparison operator in PHP is **'=='**, not '='.

Your if statement below assigns value '1' to **$first** variable and always evaluates to '1'.

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'tom-first.php';
if($first = '1') // this should be $first == '1'
{
    header("Location: startup.php");
}
else
{
    echo 'HI';
}

?>
```

Comment: *complete faceplant*

Comment: Hi @TomasCrofty if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With `=` you make an assignment (you assign a value to a variable). But `==` is a comparison operator. In your case you're evaluating `1` which is always `TRUE`. Another thing is, why so verbose and so many files if you can just write:

```
$first = file_exists('first.txt') ? 1 : 0;
```

and then the rest. Or even better...

```
if (file_exists('first.txt') {
    unlink('first.txt');
    // and do some other stuff
}
echo 'whatever';
```

But... :)
If you have to do something like this, it very much [smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).
Why would you check for the presence of a file only to delete it right away?

Comment: Thanks! I am making a template for a website where people download it and run upload the code and go through with a setup which makes a database, very much like the wordpress setup, I couldn't think of other methods of this other than having it done within a php file where $first starts as 1 and after setup is changed.